# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'url'. Either include it or remove the dependency array react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

```js
useEffect(() => {
  fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => setData(data[0]))
    .catch(err => console.warn(err))
}, [cityKey])
```

How do I solve this warning?

Answer (score 1):

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => setData(data[0]))
    .catch(err => console.warn(err))
}, [cityKey,url])
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the warning suggested solution, include `url` in the dependency array.

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => setData(data[0]))
    .catch(err => console.warn(err))
}, [cityKey, url])
```

Alternatively, you might disable the warning (but not recommended):

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => setData(data[0]))
    .catch(err => console.warn(err))
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, [cityKey])
```